# Confuse with DateTime Format on Android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite, date, datetime, datepicker

i have some problem with my app. Here is it, it's exactly not an error but i think this one need fixed for the best experience of my app.
On my app, there are a datepicker which used by user to select some date (dd-mm-yyyy) and the app will save them to the database.
Its running well, i can insert and select the Date to and from database. But what i confuse is why the Date formatted in a strange words?? I have read some books about datetime but still i can't find any way how to make my Date formatted in (dd-mm-yyyy) and show it on the list view. i use Calender.get(calender) to call the datepicker.

date column on the database now just contain value "2039" or "2040" etc and not 17-08-2015 for example.

I don't know what to do, please master help me to solve this problem.
Thanks before.

Nb. here is my code for NewTransaction (insert activity) :

```
public class NewTransaction extends ActionBarActivity {
Button btnIDate;
Button btnIAdd;
Button btnICancel;
RadioButton RdIncome;
RadioButton RdOutcome;
EditText txtAmount, txtCashflow, txtType;
DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
SQLiteDatabase db;
MainActivity mainAct = new MainActivity();
int year_x, month_x, day_x;
static final int DIALOG_ID=0;
public static long dateSelected;
public static Integer intAmount = null;
public static String month;
private boolean isUpdateTrans;
private String id, transname, transamount, transtype, transdate, transcategid;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_transaction);
    txtAmount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtAmount);
    txtCashflow = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtCashflow);
    txtType = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtType);
    RdIncome = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.RdBtnIncome);
    RdOutcome = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.RdBtnOutcome);

    String catSelected = mainAct.getCatSelected();

    onButtonClickButtonListener(catSelected);
    selectDate();
    showDialogOnClick();
    //kena null object dsni entah knapa
    Bundle bundle= getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle!= null) {
        isUpdateTrans = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("update");
        if (isUpdateTrans) {
            System.out.print("isUpdate di NewTrans");
            id = getIntent().getExtras().getString("TransId");
            transname = getIntent().getExtras().getString("TransName");
            transamount = getIntent().getExtras().getString("TransAmount");
            transtype = getIntent().getExtras().getString("TransType");
            transdate = getIntent().getExtras().getString("CategDate");
            transcategid = getIntent().getExtras().getString("CategCategId");
            txtCashflow.setText(transname);
            txtType.setText(transtype);
            txtAmount.setText(transamount);
            btnIDate.setText(transdate);

        }
    }
}

private void selectDate(){
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    year_x = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month_x = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day_x = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    switchMonth(month_x);
    btnIDate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDate);
    btnIDate.setText("Date : " + day_x + "-" + month + "-" + year_x);
    //dateSelected = (year_x+month_x+day_x);
}

public void showDialogOnClick(){
    btnIDate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDate);
    btnIDate.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showDialog(DIALOG_ID);
                }
            }
    );

}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
    if (id == DIALOG_ID)
            return  new DatePickerDialog(this, dpickerListener , year_x, month_x, day_x);
    return null;

}

private String switchMonth(Integer month_x){
    switch(month_x){
        case 1 : month = "Jan";
            break;
        case 2 : month = "Feb";
            break;
        case 3 : month = "Mar";
            break;
        case 4 : month = "Apr";
            break;
        case 5 : month = "Mei";
            break;
        case 6 : month = "Jun";
            break;
        case 7 : month = "Jul";
            break;
        case 8 : month = "Aug";
            break;
        case 9 : month = "Sep";
            break;
        case 10 : month = "Okt";
            break;
        case 11 : month = "Nov";
            break;
        case 12 : month = "Des";
            break;
    }
    return month;
}

public DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpickerListener
        = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        year_x= year;
        month_x = monthOfYear + 1;
        day_x = dayOfMonth;
        switchMonth(month_x);
        btnIDate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDate);
        btnIDate.setText("Date : " + day_x + "-" + month + "-" + year_x);
        Toast.makeText(NewTransaction.this, year_x + "/" + month_x + "/" + day_x, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//add new code
        dateSelected = view.getCalendarView().getDate();
        //DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(myDatePicker.getCalendarView().getDate());
    }
};

private void clearText(){
    txtCashflow.clearComposingText();
    txtAmount.clearComposingText();
    txtType.clearComposingText();

}

public void onButtonClickButtonListener(final String catSelected){
        btnIAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAddTrans);
        btnIAdd.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(RdIncome.isChecked()){
                            txtType.setText("Income");
                        }else{
                            txtType.setText("Outcome");
                        }
                        if (isUpdateTrans) {
                            //update
                            Toast.makeText(NewTransaction.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            intAmount = Integer.parseInt(txtAmount.getText().toString());
                            boolean isInserted = dbHelper.updateTransData(id, txtCashflow.getText().toString(),
                                    intAmount, txtType.getText().toString(), dateSelected, catSelected, null);
                            if (isInserted == true) {
                                Toast.makeText(NewTransaction.this, "Updated", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                clearText();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        NewTransaction.this,
                                        ViewCashflow.class
                                );
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else
                                Toast.makeText(NewTransaction.this, "Not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            //insert
                            Toast.makeText(NewTransaction.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            intAmount = Integer.parseInt(txtAmount.getText().toString());
                            boolean isInserted = dbHelper.insertTransData(txtCashflow.getText().toString(),
                                    intAmount, txtType.getText().toString(), dateSelected, catSelected, null);
                            if (isInserted == true) {
                                Toast.makeText(NewTransaction.this, "Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                clearText();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(
                                        NewTransaction.this,
                                        ViewCashflow.class
                                );
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else
                                Toast.makeText(NewTransaction.this, "Not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

        btnICancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCancelTrans);
        btnICancel.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(
                                NewTransaction.this,
                                MainActivity.class
                        );
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_new_transaction_, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

And this one for ViewCashFlow (activity that select data including date from database and populate them into a listView) :

```
public class ViewCashflow extends ActionBarActivity {
Button btnIDate1, btnIDate2, btnIAddNewTrans;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private static Button BtnIAddCateg;
private static Button BtnICancelCateg;
private static final String TAG = CategorySetting.class.getSimpleName();
DatabaseHelper dBHelper = new DatabaseHelper (this);
private ListView list;
int year_x, month_x, day_x;
static final int DIALOG_ID=0;
static final int DIALOG_ID2=1;
public static String month ;
public static long dateSelected1, dateSelected2;
private ArrayList<String> arrTransId = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> arrTransName = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> arrTransAmount = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> arrTransType= new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> arrTransDate= new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> arrCategId= new ArrayList<String>();
private AlertDialog.Builder build;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_cashflow);
    btnIDate1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDate1);
    btnIDate2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDate2);

    onButtonClickButtonListener();
    //calendernya lari lari
    showDialogOnClick();
    selectDate();
    displayData();
}

private void displayData() {
    db = dBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + dBHelper.TABLE_Trans_NAME  + " WHERE TransDate Between "
            + dateSelected1+" AND " + dateSelected2, null);
    list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    arrTransId.clear();
    arrTransName.clear();
    arrTransAmount.clear();
    arrTransType.clear();
    arrTransDate.clear();
    arrCategId.clear();
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            arrTransId.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(dBHelper.TOL1)));
            arrTransName.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(dBHelper.TOL2)));
            arrTransAmount.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(dBHelper.TOL3)));
            arrTransType.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(dBHelper.TOL4)));
            arrTransDate.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(dBHelper.TOL5)));
            arrCategId.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(dBHelper.TOL6)));

        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    DisplayAdapterTrans disadptr = new DisplayAdapterTrans(ViewCashflow.this, arrTransId, arrTransName,
                                arrTransAmount, arrTransType, arrTransDate, arrCategId);
    list.setAdapter(disadptr);
    mCursor.close();

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewTransaction.class);
            i.putExtra("TransId", arrTransId.get(arg2));
            i.putExtra("TransName", arrTransName.get(arg2));
            i.putExtra("TransAmount", arrTransAmount.get(arg2));
            i.putExtra("TransType", arrTransType.get(arg2));
            i.putExtra("TransDate", arrTransDate.get(arg2));
            i.putExtra("TransCategId", arrCategId.get(arg2));
            i.putExtra("update", true);
            startActivity(i);


        }
    });
}
public void onButtonClickButtonListener(){
    btnIAddNewTrans = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNewTransonView);
    btnIAddNewTrans.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            ViewCashflow.this,
                            NewTransaction.class
                    );
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }
    );
}

private void selectDate(){
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    year_x = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month_x = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day_x = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    switchMonth(month_x);
    btnIDate1.setText("Date : " + day_x + "-" + month + "-" + year_x);
    btnIDate2.setText("Date : " + day_x + "-" + month + "-" + year_x);
    dateSelected1 = (year_x+month_x+day_x);
    dateSelected2 = (year_x+month_x+day_x);
}

public void showDialogOnClick(){
    btnIDate1.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showDialog(DIALOG_ID);
                    displayData();
                }
            }
    );
    btnIDate2.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showDialog(DIALOG_ID2);
                    displayData();
                }
            }
    );

}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
    if (id == DIALOG_ID) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, dpickerListener, year_x, month_x, day_x);

    }
    else if(id == DIALOG_ID2) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, dpickerListener2, year_x, month_x, day_x);
    }
    return null;
}

private String switchMonth(Integer month_x){
    switch(month_x){
        case 1 : month = "Jan";
            break;
        case 2 : month = "Feb";
            break;
        case 3 : month = "Mar";
            break;
        case 4 : month = "Apr";
            break;
        case 5 : month = "Mei";
            break;
        case 6 : month = "Jun";
            break;
        case 7 : month = "Jul";
            break;
        case 8 : month = "Aug";
            break;
        case 9 : month = "Sep";
            break;
        case 10 : month = "Okt";
            break;
        case 11 : month = "Nov";
            break;
        case 12 : month = "Des";
            break;
    }
    return month;
}

public DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpickerListener
        = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        year_x= year;
        month_x = monthOfYear + 1;
        day_x = dayOfMonth;
        switchMonth(month_x);
        btnIDate1.setText("Date : " + day_x + "-" + month + "-" + year_x);
        dateSelected1 = (year_x+month_x+day_x);
        //Toast.makeText(ViewCashflow.this, year_x + "/" + month_x + "/" + day_x, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(ViewCashflow.this, "date " + dateSelected1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(myDatePicker.getCalendarView().getDate());
        System.out.print("date 1: " + dateSelected1);
    }
};

public DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dpickerListener2
        = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        year_x= year;
        month_x = monthOfYear + 1;
        day_x = dayOfMonth;
        switchMonth(month_x);
        btnIDate2.setText("Date : " + day_x + "-" + month + "-" + year_x);
        dateSelected2 = (year_x+month_x+day_x);
        //Toast.makeText(ViewCashflow.this, year_x + "/" + month_x + "/" + day_x, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(ViewCashflow.this, "date " + dateSelected2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(myDatePicker.getCalendarView().getDate());
        System.out.print("date 2"+ dateSelected2);
    }
};

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_view_cashflow, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `dateSelected1 = (year_x+month_x+day_x);`
It will sum those three integers instead.
17+8+2015 =  2040.

Try using `dateSelected1 = view.getCalendarView().getDate();` on the `onDateSet` method of `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener`.

Comment: i have try that sir, but i got some error "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CalendarView does not exists for the new DatePicker", what is it mean?

Comment: @iWayan What Android version do you use on the test device? Lollipop?

Comment: Yes, i use lollipop , is there any problem with my android version??

Comment: @iWayan do you have device with different android version?

Comment: Does the error occurs on `//DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(myDatePicker.getCalendarView().getDate());`?

Comment: no, the error occurs on 
`dateSelected = view.getCalendarView().getDate();`

Comment: and maybe this error occurs because i am not use DatePicker in my Xml file, i use Calendar for it,, is that matter??

Comment: I don't think so. Because I think you don't use that Calendar on your Java file, right?

Comment: i don't know, but i use this code on my java
`final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    year_x = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month_x = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day_x = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);`
is this mean i use the calendar sir?

Comment: No, if you use that code, you'll create a new Calendar instance. With the date = now.

Comment: and how can i use the calendar sir?

Comment: @iWayan What do you want to do with the calendar?

Comment: i want to use calendar for date picker, so the user can pick date from calendar.